# Marathon on math stackexchange

Tags: discussion, feature-request, allowed-questions, asking-questions, on-site-contests

everyone. Good evening. I've noticed several discussions about integral marathons and infinite series marathons on various forums, such as the Art of Problem Solving and Integrals and Series Prohbb (although the site is no longer active). Could we consider organizing an **integral or series** marathon on **Math Stack Exchange**?

Comment: (Moderator hat off, expressing a personal opinion.)  No.  This is not what the SE network is designed to do.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I recognize that Math Stack Exchange is a highly valued site, but participation may be limited to those specifically interested. Should we consider creating a tag, such as [marathon] or [challenge-problem], to distinguish these questions from those seeking essential answers?

Comment: For me it’s very great idea

Comment: I have given you my opinion.  This simply isn't what the site is for.  Math SE is not a social network.  It is not a discussion forum.  It is a Q&A site; a repository of information.  It is not designed for the kind of thing you are wanting to do.  You are trying to fit a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: @XanderHenderson what about idea of creating new tags like marathon

Comment: I’m interested in marathon on Math stack Exchange because there are legends of maths on math stackexchange so that will be very interesting

Comment: I'm not against events if they generate engagement, but I am against metatags. There is nothing stopping you from posting questions about integrals moreso than usual. But a marathon tag would be removed

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I am not a fan of questions that are posted merely to generate engagement. It's the same broken window analogy used for closed questions: allow one marathon and you don't really get to deny others. There has to be a higher purpose to asking questions than merely generating engagement or being fodder for some users here.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Sure, I mean, I wouldn't be for something where the *sole* purpose is to generate engagement. They still need to be good questions, with proper context and everything. The way I interpret the suggestion is, if the integrals fans want to get together and have an initiative for some period of time to come up with a bunch of especially good integral questions, that's certainly not outside the rules, and in my opinion is a positive thing for the site and the community.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Thanks, I see what you mean and agree with you.

Answer (score 12):

No.

Math StackExchange, like all of the sites in the StackExchange network, are designed to be repositories of useful knowledge, in the form of interesting questions and high quality answers.  StackExchange is like a wiki, not a social network or discussion forum.  For a more complete discussion of what StackExchange is (and isn't), I would recommend reading [What does StackOverflow want to be when it grows up?](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/), written by the site's founder.

The SE software is not designed to host competitions of the sort suggested here, and such a competition is a poor fit for the format.  It is wedging a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: Can I create room on chat forum?

Comment: @Martin.s https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms

Comment: Hendesrson When you find yourself wanting to have an extended conversation about a topic that is not covered by one of the existing chat rooms, you should create a new room for it” so that means yes?

Comment: @Martin.s (1) My handle is Xander Henderson, not "Henderson".  (2) I cannot give you permission to create a new chatroom.  Nor can I deny you that permission.  I have linked you to a page which explains what chat is, and how it works.  Take that as you will.

Comment: Sorry, sir. I didn't mean to disrespect you I tried to mention, but it didn't work and I accidentally removed "Xander." And I'll think about making a chat room